# Make AutoAdjust html Design Like pinterest and adjust in Angular Way?

Tags: php, html, angularjs, dom, optimization

i am Working on an social app with Angular Js where user can post different things:
For example suppose my user can post story, article , one-liner etc. 
                             
One-liner , story and article  have their own design layout . These are all coming from database. 
    Till now they have static position.

```
<div ng-repeat="line in comments.liner">
 {{line.content }} // different design pattern
 </div>
<div ng-repeat="story in comments.story">
   {{story.content }} //different design pattern
 </div>
<div ng-repeat="article in comments.article">
   {{article.content }} //different design pattern
 </div>
```

Suppose if all data come under one string like

```
<div ng-repeat="data in comments.data">
    {{data.liner }}   //different design pattern
    {{data.story }}   //different design pattern
    {{data.article }} //different design pattern
 </div>
```

How i can do this in angular so that my design could autoadjust accoding to their own different design pattern without repetition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be tricky to implement, but there are some libraries that can help. I've had some success with theses ones in tha past.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

http://masonry.desandro.com/